# List Transitions work only for "enter" not for "leave"

Tags: vue.js, transition

Following [the example in the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions), I'm using `transition-group` for a list of items. Strangely it works when items appear (`enter`), not when they disappear (`leave`), meaning they slide down in an animated fashion when appearing, but disappear instantly without animation: the `leave` animation failed. Why?

```
<template>
  <div v-if="notifications.length">
    <transition-group name="notifications">
      <span
        v-for="notification in notifications"
        :key="notification.id"
      >
        <!-- content -->
      </span>
    </transition-group>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      notifications: state => state.notifications.notifications
    })
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.notifications-enter-active,
.notifications-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.notifications-enter {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
.notifications-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

Store

```
export const mutations = {
  DELETE_NOTIFICATION (state, id) {
    state.notifications.splice(
      state.notifications.findIndex(item => item.id === id),
      1
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the exact symptom with that code ([demo 1](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/oNBmRbz)), which only transitions on `leave` instead of `enter` in your scenario. The reason for that is because the `span` is `display: inline`, which prevents the transition.

The Vue docs provide a tip for this:

> One important note is that these FLIP transitions do not work with elements set to `display: inline`. As an alternative, you can use `display: inline-block` or place elements in a `flex` context.

So, you can apply `display: flex` on the `transition-group`:

```html
<template>
  <transition-group class="container">
    ...
  </transition-group>
</template>

<style>
.container {
  display: flex;
}
</style>
```

[demo 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RwKvmLj)

Or `display: inline-block` on the `span` to be transitioned:

```html
<template>
  <span class="notification-item">
    ...
  </span>
</template>

<style>
.notification-item {
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

[demo 3](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/BapMewP)

Comment: Actually if I simply replace my `<span>` with `<div>` the situation doesn't change, `leave` transition still doesn't occur. I suppose that means the problem lies somewhere else?

Comment: Can you link to a reproduction?

Comment: I found out the culprit by accident - see my own answer (by accident because really it makes no sense why it wasn't working)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out by replacing `<div v-if="notifications.length">` with `<div v-if="notifications">` transitions now work. Even though this doesn't make any sense to me.

If anyone can explain in a comment that'd be nice :)

Comment: Assuming notifications is only an array (and not null), an array is always truthy even when empty, so `v-if="notifications"` would always evaluate to `true`. It has no meaningful effect here, and your template would do just as well without it.

Comment: I just tested it again just in case: if I add `.length`, transitions immediately stop working. If I remove it, they work again!

Comment: This is much harder to troubleshoot without a reproduction. What happens if you remove `v-if="notifications"`?

Comment: Good question, when I remove it then notifications still work. That's odd to me, because Vue transitions are supposed to require either a `v-if` or a `v-show` isn't it?

Comment: The conditional rendering is only required on the elements *within* the `<transition>`/`<transition-group>`, which is satisfied by the `v-for`. You don't actually need that outer `v-if` because `v-for` on an empty array or `null` would correctly exit.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. Looks like they don't mention that in vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions. I removed the `v-if` and indeed it works fine. Still doesn't explain why `v-if="notifications.length"` messed with transitions though. Weird.